# Activate SearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make searchbar active and show keyboard when client selects the search menu on tab bar. But resignfirstresponder doesn't work. Do yo have other suggests? Thank you for approval.
This is in my viewdidload method

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
_searchBarNew.placeholder = [MCLocalization stringForKey:@"courses"];
_searchBarNew.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"grey_background"];
_searchBarNew.delegate = self;
```

Comment: y do u want to use resignfirstresponder ?

Comment: I've used but it doesn't work

Comment: u need to call becomeFirstResponder to make textfield first responder.

Comment: uisearchBar declares the selector becomefisrtresponder

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


Once your requirement is done , tap anywhere in the screen to resign                      the keyboard

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
   [TxtFieldObj resignFirstResponder];
}
```